# How to reproduce a spared series of dates by using an iteration method

Tags: python, date, datetime, series

I am trying to create a column to add to an original dataset containing dates. Specifically, I was looking for a quick and smart method (any with iteration, if possible) to convert a string into a series of dates. In short, the result I expect is the following one:

```
2020 - 5 - 17
2020 - 12 - 12 
2021 - 2 - 13 
2022 - 5 - 17
```

I have tried the following code:

```
dates = [(2020, 5, 17), (2020, 12, 12), (2021, 2, 13), (2022, 5, 17)]

    for i in dates: 
        datetime.date(i)
        print(i)
```

That turns me back to the following error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Could someone please suggest how to text a nice code to get what I looking for? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```py
import datetime
dates = [(2020, 5, 17), (2020, 12, 12), (2021, 2, 13), (2022, 5, 17)]
for i in dates: 
    x = datetime.date(*i)
    print(x)
```

Output:

```html
2020-05-17
2020-12-12
2021-02-13
2022-05-17
```

---

If inserting into a dataframe:

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': [(2020, 5, 17), (2020, 12, 12), (2021, 2, 13), (2022, 5, 17)]})

x = []

for i in df['dates']: 
    x.append(datetime.date(*i))

df['formatted_dates'] = x
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know if it exists a method to change the format this series of dates is printed through? For example to convert format with the indent '-' with a slash '/'? Thanks again

Comment: Not sure if there is a method, but you can use `'/'.join(str(x).split('-'))`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. There are still a few problems. I would like to obtain a final object with the dates shown in the examples.  When I try to insert the column 'x' into the dataset it turns back just the first date (2020-05-17)

Comment: Do not want to force you but if you think this question might be helpful, I would invite you to upvote it. Thanks again :))